# Google Analytics Code Returns 'Undefined Function" Error

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

whatever I do, I keep getting an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error for the click tracking Google Analytics code.

The page is: http://www.purevisionmethod.com/eye-exercises/

Please, why is this happening...?

```
<script>
$('#clicked-headerbar').on('click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'website-banner', 'clicked-ad', 'headerbar', '0');
});
$('#clicked-cta-bottom').click( function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'website-banner', 'clicked-ad', 'cta-bottom', '0');
});
$('#clicked-sidebar-image-ad-1').click( function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'website-banner', 'clicked-ad', 'sidebar-ad-1', '0');
});
$('#clicked-sidebar-image-ad-2').click( function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'website-banner', 'clicked-ad', 'sidebar-ad-2', '0');
});
$('#clicked-sidebar-image-ad-3').click( function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'website-banner', 'clicked-ad', 'sidebar-ad-3', '0');
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn't related to Google Analytics.

The error is because you're including the jQuery library *after* this code which uses jQuery. Move this code below your jQuery include, or move your jQuery include to be before this code, and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

First register your tracking id on [Google Analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/). Then Google will provide you a block of code which will include some javascript code with your registered tracking id. Put that code into your webpage and then write above code below of Google Analytics code.

Answer (score 0):

I actually identified this as the offending line:

```
$('#clicked-headerbar').on('click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'website-banner', 'clicked-ad', 'headerbar', '0');
});
```

change the .on() to .click() as below:

```
$('#clicked-headerbar').click( function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'website-banner', 'clicked-ad', 'headerbar', '0');
});
```

Not sure why this is happening, however your page is loading two versions of jQuery.